# Finding the blamed commit of a bad git merge

Tags: git, merge

I ran into a strange issue with my merge script
The script in general does the below steps:

1. git checkout $source_branch
2. git checkout -f $dest_branch
3. git merge -Xtheirs --squash $source_branch -m "$commit_message"
4. git commit -m $commit_message
5. git push origin --all

It does other stuff like tag on master and create a new version etc ..

Now to the riddle
I found out that in the last merge between develop to release_candidate a chunk of code was inserted in a random location and broke the product
I looked at all the commits on develop and couldn't find a single one with this change

so is there a way to find the blamed commit even if i squashed them during the merge ?

Comment: You can use `git bisect` to find the commit where the problem first appeared.  If that commit be a non merge commit, then you have your culprit.  If it be a merge commit, then get ready to do some detective work.  In this latter case, the problem could have arisen from one parent, both parents, or it could have been introduced during the merge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... so is there a way to find the blamed commit even if i squashed them during the merge?

The short answer is no—but there may be a way to recover.

#### What squash merge is and does

This is one of the dangers of squash "merge" (which is not *a* merge at all: it uses the *merge machinery*, i.e., does "merge as a verb", but it produces a single, ordinary commit, which is not *a merge*, i.e., not "merge as a noun").  For instance, suppose you have this to start with:

```
...--o--Q--R   <-- main
      \
       A--B--C   <-- side
```

i.e., there are three commits on the side branch `side` that are not on the main branch `main`, and you then run the command:

```
git checkout main && git merge --squash side
```

What you get is this:

```
...--o--Q--R--S   <-- main
      \
       A--B--C   <-- side
```

where `S` is a new commit that holds the *work-tree result* of doing the merge.  This work-tree result is the result of combining what *you* changed (in `main`, in commits `Q` and `R`) with what *they* changed (in `side`, in commits `A`, `B`, and `C`).  That's the same combining that a regular merge would do.  But `S` is an ordinary commit, *not* a merge commit.  New commit `S` *does not* store the hash ID of commit `C`.  Git *cannot* find commit `C` through commit `S`.

If you had done a "real" merge, `S` would have a second backwards link, so that it would point back not only to commit `R` but also to commit `C`.  Git would be able to use this to locate any problem in the `A-B-C` chain.  But you told Git: *No, I don't want icky old A-B-C, throw them out, keep only S.*  This is not *wrong:* it keeps the main branch uncluttered, for instance.  But it limits your ability later, to go back and view `A-B-C` in place: that's both its great advantage, and its great disadvantage.  And that's *all* a squash merge is.

#### Finding a bug with `git bisect`

Now, just because you threw out `A-B-C` *when doing the merge,* does not mean you have thrown out `A-B-C` *entirely.*  **If you still have the name `side` pointing to commit `C`,** you can use *that* to find commit `C`.  This will let you use `git bisect` on the `A-B-C` chain.

Since this chain is, however, *not* connected to the main branch at all—there is no link from `S` back to it—you *must* run the bisect operation on the original chain, not on the squashed merge chain.  If the bug turns out to be in commit `B`, you will have to fix it separately in a commit after commit `S`, on the `main` branch (unless it's OK to *remove* `S` entirely from `main`, and you choose to do that instead).

If you *don't* have the original commits—i.e., you have deleted the side branch name `side`—then you just have to treat commit `S` as what it is: one big commit that changes a lot.  Find the bug in it.

#### Automatic resolution is dangerous

*Any* Git merge can go wrong, but adding `-X theirs` (or `-X ours`, for that matter) is especially dangerous, because it tells Git—which is *not* smart, not at all—that any *merge conflict* can be resolved by blindly choosing one of the two alternatives.

I mentioned the *merge machinery* above, and talked about combining "your changes" (commits `Q` and `R`) with "their changes" (commits `A`, `B`, and `C`).  Suppose that *they* decided that all fruit is orange, because back in commit `o` the only kind of fruit used was oranges:

```
 We have some recipes for you.
-Fruits grow on fruit trees.
+Oranges grow on orange trees.
 Blah blah ...
```

Meanwhile, *you*, in commit `Q`, added some instructions on turning apples into applesauce:

```
 We have some recipes for you.
 Fruits grow on fruit trees.
+To turn apples into applesauce, see recipe 3.
 Blah blah ...
```

Here, their change—limiting fruits to oranges only—collides with your change.  An ordinary merge would tell you that it was not sure what to do here—ut you ran `git merge -X theirs`, telling Git: "whenever there is a *problem*, throw *my* change away, and take just theirs."  So your added reference to applesauce is simply *thrown out*.  That might be OK, but it might not.  Git doesn't know, it just follows your instructions.

*Any merge requires some kind of scrutiny* (such as testing), but a merge done with "close your eyes, pick one, and hope for the best" requires *extra* scrutiny.  This is true regardless of whether you will commit the merge-as-a-verb result as a merge-as-a-noun, or as an ordinary commit that forgets the two sources of the merged work-tree.  If you *do* keep the side branch—whether by real merge, or just by keeping it—and *don't* publish the merge result immediately, you have a chance to do some good testing, or at least close proofreading, of the merge result.

If not, you set yourself up for this very problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the source commit hash in the commit message. Then you don't have to search for it.

You can also stop using `--squash`.